# how to route pages to the root of a site using zend 2 routing

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I am using zend framework 2. I want to place several pages on the root of the site. i.e

www.exampleSite.com/siteMap

i know how to get pages in a sub directory.

**i.e**

> www.exampleSite.com/support/helppage

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'supportsec' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/support[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'support\Controller\supportController',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                   ),
          ), ),  ),
```

i also know how to route to the home page i.e

```
 'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Members\Controller\HomeController',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

the confusion is how to place other pages in the root of the websites.

thanks in advance for help

i followed the advice of @exlord and place this in my module.

```
'my-static-page-1' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/my-static-page-1',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Members\Controller\HomeController',
                        'action'     => 'my-static-page-1',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

i am now able to have a page like:

```
www.exampleSite.com/examplepage
```

however the routing is only sending the route to the index for

'Members\Controller\HomeController'

i however need to send the route to the action function for examplepage i.e

```
examplepageAction(){

}
```

what do i need to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate your confusions over routing? Can you provide some example of routing to understand your problem more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic page names :

```
 'my-static-pages' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:my-page]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Members\Controller\HomeController',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

notice that this is the same as home route and it uses the index action, so in the index action you should check if the `my-page` param is set or not and act accordingly.

or you can define static routes for every page :

```
 'my-static-page-1' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/my-static-page-1',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Members\Controller\HomeController',
                        'action'     => 'my-static-page-1',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

update :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $page = $this->params()->fromRoute('my-page', false);
    if($page){
        //return a view model according to the $page parameter            
    }

    //return the original index action view model
}
```

Comment: hi Exlord. thank you so much for your help. i am a little confused though. how do you mean, that i should check if the my-page param is set and act accordingly. i normally sent pages to an action page. what action do i need to do if the page is set to the index page. i have never come across this before